# connection between curator4 and elasticsearch running into two containers

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, elasticsearch-curator

i use plindelauf/curator4 image to connect and run an action for the Elasticsearch which is running in another container. the docker ps gives:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                        NAMES
ac97b5674524        plindelauf/curator4                  "/opt/docker-entrypoi"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                                                                                     curator
e584c9b090c8        vagrant-registry.vm:5000/sslserver   "python /sslServer/ss"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:12121->12121/tcp                                                     sslserver
20eee9943664        kibana:4                             "/docker-entrypoint.s"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                                                       kibana
8c462586982e        logstash:2                           "/docker-entrypoint.s"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:5044->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12201->12201/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12201->12201/udp   logstash
c971fa3e357b        elasticsearch:2                      "/docker-entrypoint.s"   23 hours ago        Up
```

i run the container with

```
$ docker run -d -e INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES=5 -v /home/vagrant/configs:/opt/config --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch --name curator plindelauf/curator4
```

everything looks ok but when I tried to run the Curator manual i see the following error

```
root@ac97b5674524:/opt# curator --config /opt/config/curator.yml /opt/config/actionfile.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/curator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curator/curator.py", line 5, in main
    cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curator/cli.py", line 215, in cli
    client = get_client(**client_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curator/utils.py", line 566, in get_client
    'Error: {0}'.format(e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ElasticsearchException: Unable to create client connection to Elasticsearch.  Error: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f144c062f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f144c062f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

I believe the --link is correct. I am new on that stuff so I do not know what is going on. i am not sure if i have to provide you the config file for the curator, too. just let me know if so.

Answer (score 0):

ok. the problem in my case was just the given ip in the curator.yml. When I changed 127.0.0.1 to the ip where elastic was running the problem solved

Comment: try using 0.0.0.0 instead as the container might get different IPs each run

Comment: I have tried that but i get the same exception. Does this make any sense in this configuration?

Comment: usually it means that the process will listen on any available IP. Either that or "*", but it depends on the software itself.

Comment: yeah obviously. i just try to why it doesnt work in this case. however the hostname does the work.

Comment: I'm sorry, now that I read it again, I see that what you have changed is the target IP (which Curator is connecting to), not the Elasticsearch's listening IP. What I meant is that you should put Elasticsearch to listen to any IP (0.0.0.0) and the ideal is to make Curator connect using DNS, not it's IP.